# Why typescript translate const to var?

Tags: typescript, tsc

I worte some code to test typescript how to translate ts -> js.

```
const printX = (name: string) => console.log(`hello, ${name}!`)
const tt = () => {
 const t1 = 123;
const t2 = 456;

}
```

I checked the translated js file and it was,

```
var printX = function (name) { return console.log("hello, ".concat(name, "!")); };
var tt = function () {
    var t1 = 123;
    var t2 = 456;
};
```

Why Typescript translate from const keyword to var keyword.

I'm wondering if I can make ts translate force const to const.

Comment: go into your `tsconfig.json` and set the target version to `ES2015` or higher.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the [`target` in your tsconfig](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#target) to something above ES5, and then ES6 syntax (such as `const`) will be preserved.

> Modern browsers support all ES6 features, so ES6 is a good choice. You might choose to set a lower target if your code is deployed to older environments, or a higher target if your code is guaranteed to run in newer environments.
>
> The target setting changes which JS features are downleveled and which are left intact. For example, an arrow function `() => this` will be turned into an equivalent function expression if target is ES5 or lower.

Comment: At first, I tried to tsc with es6 setting in tsconfig.json. However, the result was compiled to var. Now, I realized my tsc command was global install version and not compile with tsconfig.json.